# How to replace lookahead in regex?

Tags: regex, oracle

I wrote a regex that validates an input string. It must have a minimum length of 8 chars (composed by alphanumeric and punctuation chars) and it must have at least one digit and one alphabetic char. So I've come up with the regex:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9-,._;:]{8,}$
```

Now I have to rewrite this regex in a language that doesn't support lookahead, how should I rewrite that regex?

Valid inputs are:

```
1foo,bar
foo,bar1
1fooobar
foooobar1
fooo11bar
1234x567
a1234567
```

Invalid inputs:

```
fooo,bar
1234-567
.1234567
```

Comment: Stating the language might help, since support for different features varies.

Comment: @Josh: The question is tagged "perl".

Comment: @mu Is there an implementation of Perl that doesn't support look-aheads?

Comment: @Josh: Not one that doesn't smell exceedingly musty, I see your point about the "language that doesn't support lookahead" though.

Comment: Your second invalid input `1234x567` has 8 characters, composed by alphanumeric and punctuation chars, one digit, and one alphabetic char. Why is it invalid?

Comment: Lookahead assertions are zero-length assertions like `^`, `$`, and `\b`.

Comment: @Josh: I've to rewrite the Perl regex above using Oracle regex functions

Comment: Please do not delete comments even if they contain a factual error. It makes it hard for those who come after us to follow the discussion.

Comment: @user601423 Still looking for why `1234x567` is listed as invalid input. I brought this up in an earlier comment.

Comment: @MetaEd You're right, my previous second invalid input was actually valid. I've corrected my question. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two approaches. One is to compose a single expression which handles all possible alternatives:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-,._;:]{6,}$
  |
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-,._;:][0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-,._;:]{5,}$
  |
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-,._;:]{2}[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-,._;:]{4,}$
```

etc. This is a combinatoric nightmare, but it would work.

A much simpler approach is to validate the same string twice using two expressions:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-,._;:]{8,}$          # check length and permitted characters
```

and

```
[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]  # check required characters
```

EDIT: @briandfoy correctly points out that it will be more efficient to search for each required character separately:

```
[a-zA-Z]                         # check for required alpha
```

and

```
[0-9]                            # check for required digit
```

Comment: Your second regex is a lot of repeated work. Use two separate regexes to check for a alpha and a numeric: qr/[a-z]/i and qr/[0-9

Comment: @MetaEd I was looking for a single line regex, but there isn't a trivial one without using a feature like lokkahead. I'll go with your 2nd solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**This question was original tagged as `perl`, and that's how I answered it. For the oracle stuff, I have no idea how you'd do the same thing. However, I'd try to validate this stuff before it got that far.**

I wouldn't do this in one regular expression. When you decide to change the rules, you'll have the same amount of work to craft the new regular expression. I wouldn't use lookarounds for this even if they were available since I wouldn't want to tolerate all the backtracking.

This looks like it's a lot of code, but the part that addresses your problem is just the subroutine. It has very simple patterns. When the password rules change, you add or delete patterns. It might be worth it to use [study](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/study.html), but I didn't investigate that:

```
use v5.10;
use strict;

use Test::More;

my @valids = qw(
    1foo,bar
    foo,bar1
    1fooobar
    foooobar1
    fooo11bar
    );

my @invalids = qw( 
    fooo,bar
    short
    nodigitbutlong
    12345678
    ,,,,,,,,
    );

sub is_good_password {
    my( $password ) = @_;

    state $rules = [
        qr/\A[A-Z0-9,._;:-]{8,}\z/i,
        qr/[0-9]/,
        qr/[A-Z]/i,
        ];

    foreach my $rule ( @$rules ) {
        return 0 unless $password =~ $rule;
        }

    return 1;
    }       

foreach my $valid ( @valids ) {
    ok( is_good_password( $valid ), "Password $valid is valid" );
    }

foreach my $invalid ( @invalids ) {
    ok( ! is_good_password( $invalid ), "Password $invalid is invalid" );
    }

done_testing();
```

Comment: I've tagged it as 'Perl' because I've to port it from Perl to Oracle. I didn't specify the 'destination' language because there are several languages that don't support lookahead and because I'm more interested in the regex itself than the implementation language.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with right now is

```
(.*[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*|.*[0-9].*[a-zA-Z].*)
```

But you have to check the length of the string separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would play around with these ideas to get the best performance:

- should be faster for short valid inputs, but will be slower (backtrack) for inputs like "0a000000000000000000" or "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa":

  ```
  regexp_like(regexp_substr(input_string, '^[a-zA-Z0-9_,.;:-]{8,}$'),
              '[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]')
  ```
- should be faster if there are a lot of invalid inputs (don't miss [^...] on the 2nd line):

  ```
  (length(input_string) >= 8 and
   not regexp_like(input_string, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_,.;:-]') and
   regexp_like(input_string, '[a-zA-Z]') and
   regexp_like(input_string, '[0-9]'))
  ```