# Using LookAhead to ensure there is at least one % in a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to add a condition in a below given regular expression to check there is at least one special character of `%` (percent sign) that starts with `W` with additional five characters that could be between `A-Z`, `0-9` and `%`. I tried on my own to use LookAhead `(?=.*[%])`, but unfortunately not working for me. Below is an expression I would like to check there is at least one or more `%` characters in a string using lookahead or by some other syntax. Thanks in advance.

Trying to add lookahead on this expression:

```
Select 'P' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE('W77%7%','(^W[0-9A-Z%]{5}$)')
```

Tried:

```
Select 'P' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE('W77%7%','^(?=(^%){0,6}) [^W[0-9A-Z%]{5}$]')
```

Tried:

```
Select 'P' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE('W77%7%','^(?=.*%){0,6}) [^W[0-9A-Z%]{5}$]')
```

Comment: iirc, oracle regexen do not support lookahead.

Comment: That's really unfortunate. Is there other way to check in an above expression that it contains at least one % special character. Thanks.

Select 'P' from dual Where REGEXP_LIKE('W77%7%','(^W[0-9A-Z%]{5}$)')

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306521/how-to-replace-lookahead-in-regex

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's regular expression engine is basically POSIX ERE regular expressions with some enhancements, which means, among other things, no lookarounds. But I'm not sure I understand why you would need lookahead in order to determine whether a particular string contains a `%` character.

```
SELECT 'P' FROM dual
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('W77%7%', '^W[0-9A-Z%]{5}$')
   AND INSTR('W77%7%', '%') > 0;
```

P.S. If Oracle *did* support lookahead in its regular expressions, I think the regular expression you would be looking for would look something like this:

```
^(?=.*%)W[0-9A-Z%]{5}$
```

[See Regex demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/mQ4xE5/1)

**UPDATE** It is possible to do this in Oracle with a single regex and no other conditions, but it isn't pretty. Basically you have to account for each possible position of `%`:

```
SELECT 'P' FROM dual
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('W77%7%', '^W(%[0-9A-Z%]{4}|[0-9A-Z%]%[0-9A-Z%]{3}|[0-9A-Z%]{2}%[0-9A-Z%]{2}|[0-9A-Z%]{3}%[0-9A-Z%]|[0-9A-Z%]{4}%)');
```